# parametric equation for hyperbola like $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Tags: calculus, parametric

How can I get this  parametric equation $x=\frac a2\left(t+\frac1t\right)$ and $y=\frac b2\left(t-\frac1t\right)$ for hyperbola like  $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ using this $xy=1$ ($x=t$, $y=\frac 1t$, $t\neq 0$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Thes

Comment: The left hand side is a difference between squares, so the equation can be written as $$ (\dfrac{x}{a} - \dfrac{y}{b}) (\dfrac{x}{a} + \dfrac{y}{b} ) = 1 $$  From here if we take $ \dfrac{x}{a} - \dfrac{y}{b} = t $ then we have to take $ \dfrac{x}{a} + \dfrac{y}{b} = \dfrac{1}{t} $.  From these two equations you can solve for $x$ and $y$.  It's just a $2 \times 2 $ linear system in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: The equation in the title, for $a=b=1$ is a hyperbola rotated $45^\circ$ with respect to $xy=1$ hyperbola

Answer (score 0):

The parametric point for a hyperbola can be given by (asecθ, btanθ) where you can put cot(θ/2) as t and get your result